# issue while printing ireport with selected Font

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am printing a JasperReport using java. I have set the font for each text field in the report separately, but while printing printer does not print in selected font Arial at size 9. If report is exported to docx file then the docx prints the report in correct font.

Comment: Try selecting the option to embed the fonts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure what Arial is available to JVM. I belive that is usually not a problem on Windows, but you should use font extensions or add fonts to a JVM fonts folder under Linux.